# Java - cast exception in comparable

Tags: java, classcastexception, comparable

I have this method:

```
private SortedMap<String, SpaceObjectImpl> catalog = new TreeMap<String, SpaceObjectImpl>();

public Collection<SpaceObject> getSpaceObjects(){
    SortedSet<SpaceObject> temp = new TreeSet<SpaceObject>(catalog.values());
    return temp;
}
```

while compareTo is defined here:

```
public int compareTo(SpaceObjectImpl s){
    ....
}

class SpaceObjectImpl implements SpaceObject
```

When i run program, `ClassCastException` is thrown. Any idea why?

error:

```
SpaceObjectImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable(in TreeMap)
```

Comment: You need to have SpaceObjectImpl implement Comparable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `SpaceObjectImpl`  must implement `Comparable` interface.

The following is [an example by mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/) that illustrates this concept:

```
public class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit>{

    private String fruitName;
    private String fruitDesc;
    private int quantity;

    public Fruit(String fruitName, String fruitDesc, int quantity) {
        super();
        this.fruitName = fruitName;
        this.fruitDesc = fruitDesc;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getFruitName() {
        return fruitName;
    }
    public void setFruitName(String fruitName) {
        this.fruitName = fruitName;
    }
    public String getFruitDesc() {
        return fruitDesc;
    }
    public void setFruitDesc(String fruitDesc) {
        this.fruitDesc = fruitDesc;
    }
    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public int compareTo(Fruit compareFruit) {

        int compareQuantity = ((Fruit) compareFruit).getQuantity(); 

        //ascending order
        return this.quantity - compareQuantity;

        //descending order
        //return compareQuantity - this.quantity;

    }   
}
```

Here, the `Fruit` class has implemented `Comparable` interface with type as `Fruit` and has also `overriden` `compareTo` method.

Comment: -1 You keep copying stuff without proper attribution. http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Comment: Simply adding a link at the very end isn't good enough for attribution in this case. I've edited your answer to make it a little more clear where the code example was drawn from.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani - seriously, do you understand what plagiarism is?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism.  Between copying answers and tag wikis, this is getting a little old.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I agree your thing also mentioned the site from where I have taken the example.

Answer (score 1):

`SpaceObjectImpl` must implement `Comparable<SpaceObjectImpl>`.

Answer (score 0):

compareTo method is defined in Comparable which your custom class should override for using it in TreeMap.Please implement the comparable interface in your custom class

Answer (score 0):

You have written your own `compareTo()` method. You need to write your own `compareTo()` but, that needs to be over-ridden, i.e. your class should implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29)

> Lists (and arrays) of objects **that implement this interface** can be sorted automatically by Collections.sort (and Arrays.sort).

Answer (score 0):

All sorted Data Structure/Collection, sorting is done depending on its compareTo method. In your case object is user defined so bydefault there is no compareTo method in that class. You have to implement the

```
 Comparable
```

and override it's compareTo method according to your sorting criteria logic.

More info can be found at http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Hope this will help.